# Dealing with empty cells when importing Excel file using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception, epplus

I want to import data from Excel to DataBase using EPPLUS. From here I took code: https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt6

The problem is that sometimes in excel are empty Cells. And if cell is empty then I receive an error: `NullReferenceException`, and my application stops. I think good solution would be assign `null` value to specific variable if there is no reference e.g. `if(LAST_NAME returns NullReferenceException then LAST_NAME = null)` - but I don't know how to do this in code.

```
var newRecord = new DB_USER
{
    ID = Int32.Parse(worksheet.Cells[idColumn + row].Value.ToString()),
    FIRST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[firstNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
    LAST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[lastNameColumn + row].Value.ToString() //If this value has NullReferenceException then assign null or ""
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thing its fine to assign a empty string i.e. `string.Empty` for empty cells .And if you are fine you can put it this way :

```
var newRecord = new DB_USER
      {
           ID = Int32.Parse(worksheet.Cells[idColumn + row].Value.ToString()),
           FIRST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[firstNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
           LAST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[lastNameColumn + row].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString() //for a null value assign a empty string else the string value
       };
```

A cleaner approach would be Extension method :

```
public static string ToNullSafeString(this object obj)
{
    return (obj ?? string.Empty).ToString();
}
```

and use it as :

```
LAST_NAME = worksheet.Cells[lastNameColumn + row].Value.ToNullSafeString();
```

still if you wish to return a `null` instead of `string.Empty` then a slight modification to `ToNullSafeString` extension method above will work.

Comment: Second way with extension method works almost good. But returns e.g `"D2"` (it's address CELL) instead string.empty. // EDIT - you forgot to add `.Value` before `.ToNullSafeString();`. Please edit your answer and i'll mark it :)

Comment: What if I have INT instead string? eg. `SKILL1 = Int32.Parse(worksheet6.Cells[skill1Column + row].Value.ToNullSafeString()),` It doesn't work in this case. I have an error: `Invalid format of the input string.`

Comment: That's correct , It will fail as you are using `Int32.Parse` and it is trying to parse null into `integer.Int32`.Parse isn't capable of parsing a null value.You will need your own helper method to it.

Comment: So what can I do now? Some Cells are numbers.

Comment: I think this is what you need instead of Int32.parse write a extension `public static int? ToNullableInt32(this string s)
{
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
    return null;
}`      also you will call it like this `SKILL1 = (worksheet6.Cells[skill1Column + row].Value.ToNullSafeString().ToNullableInt32());` hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest C# version (6.0) then you can use the [null propagation operator](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883):

```
LAST_NAME = worksheet?.Cells[lastNameColumn + row]?.Value?.ToString()
```

Comment: I can't :( I have VS2013

Comment: @DiPix C# 6 can be used with VS 2013.

Comment: @mason So I don't know why i can't Build application: `syntax error`

Comment: I was stuck on that and it has just saved me!

Comment: Me too! this's my solution!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases NAN consider as a string to deal such NAN string values in column using EPPlus I have overcome to this issue using this method . Try

if (AbcFileName.Name.Contains("abc"))
{

```
                int rows = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                int cols = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

                // Loop through each row and column in the worksheet
                for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= cols;col++) 
                    {
                        // Get the cell value as a string
                        string cellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, col].GetCellValue<string>();
                        

                        // Check for "NAN" values and replace them with a blank value
                        if (cellValue == "NaN")
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = "NAN".ToUpper();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```